# Generate token fails for Azure app which is both client and API (client credentials workflow)

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We are not able to generate a token for an app which is at the same time offering an API and acts as a client for another app. We want to use the client credentials workflow in OAuth.

The app ApiAndClient has client credentials and the permission to use the api of app ApiApp.
We granted the ApiAndClient app admin consent to use the api of ApiApp.
We configured a redirect URI in ApiApp.
When we want to issue a token for ApiAndClient, the following error message comes up:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "AADSTS501461: AcceptMappedClaims is only supported for a token audience matching the application GUID or an audience within the tenant's verified domains. Either change the resource identifier, or use an application-specific signing key.\r\nTrace ID: XXXXX\r\nCorrelation ID: XXXXXXXXX\r\nTimestamp: 2020-09-04 07:40:31Z",
  "error_codes": [
    501461
  ],
  "timestamp": "2020-09-04 07:40:31Z",
  "trace_id": "XXXXXX",
  "correlation_id": "XXXXXX"
}
```

We compared the settings of both ApiAndClient and ApiApp to other apps, where the token works.
There is one difference in the ApiApp, it has"acceptMappedClaims" set to true, other api app have set to null. If we set that to null, the error message changes:

```
"AADSTS50146: This application is required to be configured with an application-specific signing key. It is either not configured with one, or the key has expired or is not yet valid.\r\nTrace ID: xxxxxx\r\nCorrelation ID: xxxxxxx\r\nTimestamp: 2020-09-04 08:15:26Z",
```

Setting it to false does not change anything.

We have the suspicion, that the client app which acts also as a api might be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep `acceptMappedClaims` as true.

Now that ApiAndClient is also used as an API app, you should click on **Expose an API** and **Set** the Application ID URI, which will be treated as the tenant's verified domain.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Allen. I set the Application ID URI initially, as I set up the API already (including scopes). We found out that the pre-generated URI is not fitting to our scenario, though. See my answer below.

Comment: @guerda Sorry maybe I didn't make it clear. Setting the Application ID URI as `https://companyname.com` should be able to fix this problem. Setting `identifierUris` in manifest can also do the same thing. I'm not saying set the Application ID URI initially. You should set it as your verified domain. I know you use custom claims. So keeping `acceptMappedClaims` as true is necessary, which will require you to set the verified domain in `identifierUris`. Anyway, the cause of this issue is you didn't set a verified domain in identifierUris.

Comment: With that clarification, it's definitely the correct answer, thank you, Allen!

Comment: @guerda NP:) Glad to know everything is OK now.

Answer (score 0):

There was a completely different problem which I was able to fix with some AD expert.

We use custom claims in our AD. Therefore, the application scope must start with a verified domain (https://companyname.com/).
Otherwise the token was not generated. Now that I changed it, the token can be generated.